# SQL query for selecting data from same table for different periods

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I would like to fetch individual pay for my employees for respective months in the year 2012. Here is the code.

```
SELECT 
jd.job_grade,
e.employee_title||'. '|| e.first_name||' '||e.initials||' '||e.surname as FULLNAME,
e.employee_code,
sum(NVL(jan.amount,0)) as JAN_PAY,
sum(NVL(feb.amount,0)) as FEB_PAY,
sum(NVL(mar.amount,0)) as MAR_PAY,
sum(NVL(apr.amount,0)) as APR_PAY,
sum(NVL(may.amount,0)) as MAY_PAY,
sum(NVL(jun.amount,0)) as JUN_PAY,
sum(NVL(jul.amount,0)) as JUL_PAY,
sum(NVL(aug.amount,0)) as AUG_PAY,
sum(NVL(sep.amount,0)) as SEP_PAY,
sum(NVL(oct.amount,0)) as OCT_PAY,
sum(NVL(nov.amount,0)) as NOV_PAY,
sum(NVL(ar.amount,0)) as DEC_PAY/*,
0.05*sum(NVL(ar.amount,0)) as Bonus*/ 
from (((((((((((((tbl_actual_run ar
JOIN tbl_actual_run JAN ON jan.emp_code=ar.emp_code)
JOIN tbl_actual_run FEB ON feb.emp_code=ar.emp_code)
JOIN tbl_actual_run MAR ON mar.emp_code=ar.emp_code)
JOIN tbl_actual_run APR ON apr.emp_code=ar.emp_code)
JOIN tbl_actual_run MAY ON may.emp_code=ar.emp_code)
JOIN tbl_actual_run JUN ON jun.emp_code=ar.emp_code) 
JOIN tbl_actual_run JUL ON jul.emp_code=ar.emp_code)
JOIN tbl_actual_run AUG ON aug.emp_code=ar.emp_code)
JOIN tbl_actual_run SEP ON sep.emp_code=ar.emp_code)
JOIN tbl_actual_run OCT ON oct.emp_code=ar.emp_code)
JOIN tbl_actual_run NOV ON nov.emp_code=ar.emp_code) 
JOIN TBL_EMPLOYEE E ON E.EMPLOYEE_CODE=ar.emp_code) 
JOIN tbl_job_details jd ON jd.employee_code=ar.emp_code) 
where (ar.payroll_date LIKE '%DEC-12%' and ar.ed_code in ('0001','0011','0012','0003')) 
and  (nov.Payroll_Date LIKE'%NOV-12%'and nov.ed_code in ('0001','0011','0012','0003'))
and (oct.Payroll_Date LIKE'%OCT-12%' and oct.ed_code in ('0001','0011','0012','0003'))
and (sep.Payroll_Date LIKE'%SEP-12%' and oct.ed_code in ('0001','0011','0012','0003'))
and (aug.Payroll_Date LIKE'%AUG-12%' and aug.ed_code in ('0001','0011','0012','0003'))
and (jul.Payroll_Date LIKE'%JUL-12%' and jul.ed_code in ('0001','0011','0012','0003'))
and (jun.Payroll_Date LIKE'%JUN-12%' and jun.ed_code in ('0001','0011','0012','0003'))
and (may.Payroll_Date LIKE'%MAY-12%' and may.ed_code in ('0001','0011','0012','0003'))
and (apr.Payroll_Date LIKE'%APR-12%' and apr.ed_code in ('0001','0011','0012','0003'))
and (mar.Payroll_Date LIKE'%MAR-12%' and mar.ed_code in ('0001','0011','0012','0003'))
and (feb.Payroll_Date LIKE'%FEB-12%' and feb.ed_code in ('0001','0011','0012','0003'))
and (jan.Payroll_Date LIKE'%JAN-12%' and jan.ed_code in ('0001','0011','0012','0003'))
GROUP BY jd.job_grade,e.employee_title,e.first_name,e.initials,e.surname,e.employee_code 
order by TO_NUMBER(jd.job_grade) DESC, e.first_name,e.surname
```

The problem is

1. the figures are accumulative not reflecting how each individual in each month recieved.
2. the indiviuals who were employed or fired within the year year are not showing up

Note:

- TBL_ACTUAL_RUN is where all monthly salaries are kept
- TBL_Employee is where all employees are kept
- TBL_JOB_Details is where Employee job information is kept

Can anyone assist? Your assistance will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you give the table structures as DDL, and sample data? Preferably at SQL Fiddle, but in alternatively in the question.

Comment: What version of oracle are you using?  If you are using Oracle11g+ I might suggest using the `PIVOT` function. You could eliminate the number of joins, even without the `PIVOT` this can be done with not so many joins

Comment: instead of putting this query simple post the structure of your table with some sample data. The solution is much simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too long for a comment so I am posting this as an answer.  I think you will have a hard time debugging your query with all of those joins.  Here is a version that might be easier to debug without all of the joins. This is doing the same thing, except you are using the aggregate with a `CASE` statement to decide each month. The syntax would be similar to this:

```
SELECT jd.job_grade,
  e.employee_title||'. '|| e.first_name||' '||e.initials||' '||e.surname as FULLNAME,
  e.employee_code,
  sum(case when ar.payroll_date LIKE '%JAN-12%' then ar.amount else 0 end) JAN_PAY,
  sum(case when ar.payroll_date LIKE '%FEB-12%' then ar.amount else 0 end) FEB_PAY,
  sum(case when ar.payroll_date LIKE '%MAR-12%' then ar.amount else 0 end) MAR_PAY,
  sum(case when ar.payroll_date LIKE '%APR-12%' then ar.amount else 0 end) APR_PAY,
  sum(case when ar.payroll_date LIKE '%MAY-12%' then ar.amount else 0 end) MAY_PAY,
  sum(case when ar.payroll_date LIKE '%JUN-12%' then ar.amount else 0 end) JUN_PAY,
  sum(case when ar.payroll_date LIKE '%JUL-12%' then ar.amount else 0 end) JUL_PAY,
  sum(case when ar.payroll_date LIKE '%AUG-12%' then ar.amount else 0 end) AUG_PAY,
  sum(case when ar.payroll_date LIKE '%SEP-12%' then ar.amount else 0 end) SEP_PAY,
  sum(case when ar.payroll_date LIKE '%OCT-12%' then ar.amount else 0 end) OCT_PAY,
  sum(case when ar.payroll_date LIKE '%NOV-12%' then ar.amount else 0 end) NOV_PAY,
  sum(case when ar.payroll_date LIKE '%DEC-12%' then ar.amount else 0 end) DEC_PAY
from tbl_actual_run ar
left join TBL_EMPLOYEE E 
  ON E.EMPLOYEE_CODE=ar.emp_code 
left JOIN tbl_job_details jd 
  ON jd.employee_code=ar.emp_code) 
where ar.payroll_date LIKE '%-12%' 
  and ar.ed_code in ('0001','0011','0012','0003')
group by jd.job_grade,e.employee_title,e.first_name,e.initials,e.surname,e.employee_code
order by TO_NUMBER(jd.job_grade) DESC, e.first_name,e.surname
```

Comment: I was looking for this solution, Thank you very much

Comment: I was looking for this solution, Thank you very much